# How can I repair the GRUB using Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, ati, hp, windows-8, uefi

I am running on a HP Envy DV6 laptop with an AMD A8. It has windows 8. I installed Ubuntu from a LiveUSB that I created, but it wont give me the option to boot into it.

I disabled *secureboot* and *fastboot*, but that didn't help. Another thing I noticed is after I installed a Local Disk `F:` was created, that windows wants to format and has 99GB of storage space.

I also ran boot repair inside the Ubuntu trial and got this:

```
Boot successfully repaired.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5653811/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair<at>gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/grub/shimx64.efi file!

A broken Wubi has been detected. Please fix it this way:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't see an entry for Ubuntu in the Boot devices selection menu, UEFI Boot Sources? It's the screen in Fig.16 in this [HP support article](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=5296055&prodTypeId=321957&objectID=c03483233). About the letter F, it is your root Ubuntu partition, don't format it, just remove the assigned letter in Windows Disk Management, so it won't bother you further.

Comment: I did find an entry there, and it works and i can boot into it.